Krull dimension in non-algebraically closed fields
Let $K$ be a field (not algebraically closed) and $F$ be its algebraic closure.
Let $X \subseteq K^n$ be Zariski closed, and $Y$ be the Zariski closure of $X$ inside $F^n$.
Is it true that $\dim(X) = \dim(Y)$?
By $\dim(Z)$ I mean the Krull dimension of the Noetherian topological space $Z$ (maximum length of a chain of irreducible subsets of $Z$).
It is easy to see that $\dim(X) \leq \dim(Y)$, and that, in general, a subset $Z$ and its closure can have different dimensions.
If equality fails, I would like an example with $K = \mathbb R$; if instead equality is always true, I would like a reference (but of course proofs and discussions are welcome).

Do you mean something like $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$ in $\mathbf R^3$, which has only one $\mathbf R$-point, but over $\mathbf C$ becomes a surface? Or do you mean dimension in the scheme-theoretic sense, regardless of whether $X$ has enough points defined over $K$?

I mean neither. Treat $K^n$ and $F^n$ as topological spaces (ignore completely the algebra and geometry).  Thus, if $X$ is finite, its closure inside $F^n$ is equal to $X$ itself. Example: if $K = \mathbb R$, let $Z \subset \mathbb R^2$ be the graph of the exponential function. Then $\dim(Z) = 1$, but the dimension of the Zariskl closure of $Z$ is 2 (because the closure is all $\mathbb R^2$).

Ah I see, I didn't read it correctly. I'll leave my comment up in case someone else has the same confusion.

This holds for all fields that are “big” or “ample” in the sense of Florian Pop.  In particular, it holds for the field of real numbers.

@JasonStarr can you give a reference, please? I may mention this fact in a paper

@JasonStarr it would be nice to make this an answer with a reference

This is not true for an arbitrary field $K$. It may be true for $K= \mathbb R$.
Let $K=\mathbb Q$ and let $A$ be a simple abelian surface over $\mathbb Q$ with positive Mordell-Weil rank. Then $A(K)$ is Zariski dense in $A(F)$ so $A(K)$ is a Zariski closed subset of $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb Q)$. Restricting to some affine hyperplane, we get a Zariski closed subset of $\mathbb A^n(\mathbb Q)$. However, every proper Zariski closed subset of $A(\mathbb Q)$ is finite: It is the set of $\mathbb Q$-points of some curve, which can't be genus $0$ because $A$ is an abelian variety, and can't be genus $1$ because $A$ is simple, so must have finitely many rational points by Faltings' theorem. So the Krull dimension of $X$ (which is $A(\mathbb Q)$ minus finitely many points) is $1$, not $2= \dim A$ which is the Krull dimension of the Zariski closure of $A$.

Thank you for your answer. Since I'm not familiar with many of the terms you use, could you give an explicit form (i.e. the equations for the example)? E.g.: how large is n?

@AntongiulioFornasiero Let $f$ be a polynomial in one variable of degree $5$ over $\mathbb Q$. One can express $f(x)f(y)$ as a polynomial $g(s_1,s_2)$ in $s_1=x+y$ and $s_2=x+y$. Then the  pair of equations $z^2 = g(s_1,s_2),  w(s_1^2-4s_2)=1$ in four variables $s_1,s_2, z,w$ is expected to work for about half of polynomials $f$, and it is easy but not enlightening to find an explicit $f$ that works. Probably a 3 variable version can be done as well.

There's a misprint: maybe you meant $s_2 = x-y$?

@AntongiulioFornasiero Rather I meant $xy$, apologies.

If I understand correctly, one of the claims is that the set of triples $(s_1, t, z) \in L^3: z^2 = f(s_1 + \sqrt t)f(s_1 - \sqrt t) \wedge t \neq 0$ has  dimension 1 if $L = \mathbb Q$, while it has dimension 2 if $L= \mathbb C$ (for many choices of $f$)...

$\DeclareMathOperator\algdim{algdim}$Here is a proof of what Jason Starr claimed (at least, in characteristic 0).
Let $K$ be a large field (in the sense of [Pop]) of characteristic $0$ and $F$ be its algebraic closure. Let $X\subseteq K^n$; define the algebraic dimension of $X$ as the Krull dimension of the Zariski closure $Y$ of $X$ inside $F^n$ (see [Dries]). If $X$ is Zariski closed inside $K^n$, then $\dim(X)$, the Krull dimension of $X$ (as a Noetherian topological space), is equal to its algebraic dimension.
Proof. By [Pop], we can assume that $K \subseteq K[[t]] \subseteq K^*$, where $K^*$ is an ultrapower of $K$. The same equations that define $Y$ also define some set $X' \subseteq K[[t]]^n$ and $X^* \subseteq (K^*)^n$. Since $K^*$ is an ultrapower of $K$ we have that $\dim(X) = \dim(X^*)$ and $\algdim(X) = \algdim(X^*)$. Since both $\dim$ and $\algdim$ are increasing, it suffices to show that $\dim(X') \geq \algdim(X')$. Thus, w.l.o.g., we may assume that $K$ is a Henselian field of characteristic $0$. By [Dries] Corollary 3.13, the projection of $X$ on some $K^d$ contains an open set $U$ (where $d := \algdim(X)$). Moreover, $\dim(U) =d$ and therefore $\dim(X) \geq d$.
[Dries] Dries, Lou van den. 1989. “Dimension of Definable Sets, Algebraic Boundedness and Henselian Fields.” Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 45:189–209.
[Pop] Pop, Florian. 2014. “Little Survey on Large Fields - Old & New.” In Valuation Theory in Interaction, 432–63. Congress Reports. European Mathematical Society.
There is the issue if the condition that $K$ is large is necessary….

On the real the proof is even easier: one can work directly inside $\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean topology. If $algdim(X) = d$, then the projection of $X$ on some $\mathbb R^d$ contains an  Euclidean open set, and therefore $dim(X) \geq d$.

When you say "There is the issue if the condition that $K$ is large is necessary…", maybe you mean whether it is an exact characterisation—and that would be a piece of luck!—but of course @WillSawin's answer shows that certainly some condition is necessary.

@LSpice yes I meant: is it true that a field (of char 0) is large if and only if, for every X Zariski closed subset of $K^n$, $dim(X) = algdim(X)$? A possible candidate for a counterexample could be : Johnson, Will, and Jinhe Ye. 2023. “Curve-Excluding Fields,” 1–30. http://arxiv.org/abs/2303.06063.

Thank you for writing out the details.

My mistake: all algebraically bounded fields (and in particular the in particular the curve-excluding fields) satisfy the condition.

Would you copy the definition of a "large in the sense of Pop" field? Your links point to paywalls.

Definition. A field k is called a large field, if for every irreducible k-curve C the following holds: If C
has a k-rational smooth point, then C has infinitely many k-rational points.
Here is the link on Pop webpage: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~pop/Research/files-Res/LF_6Oct2013.pdf
